# Not able to trigger the stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Executing the following command but the database table isn't reflecting the changes it should:

```
declare v_ver_number NUMBER;
Begin
 begin_tran;
  v_ver_number := 1;

extension_security_insert_row ('olfdoc_export_type' ,0 ,1 ,'olfdoc_export_type_h','update_user','last_update','update_type', 20104 , v_ver_number);

commit_tran;
End;
```

Comment: maybe the source of extension_security_insert_row?..

Comment: the source of the stored procedure is the core stored procedure of an application . 
When I run the same sql directly from the Oracle then it reflects the changes. But cannot run the same on production database due to access issues.

Comment: my point is - you run procedure, not function, so you get no return. In case you catch exceptions or use some not transparent UI like dblink or so, you not necessarily see the error. Who can tell what gone wrong with no source? :) It may be permissions, maybe different data, maybe deadlock, maybe wrong logical order, really - whatever... If you say you run SQL from procedure and it works, I can tell SQL is probbably not the reason for the error :)